# Confused about the string pointer iteration in my lecture notes

Tags: c

This is the chunk of code I've copied from my lecture notes

```
/* 2D processing */
printf("\n");
for (i=0; i<3; i++)
    for (j=0; j<3; j++)
        printf("%d ", *(*(ar+i)+j) );
```

Since `ar` is the pointer referring the address location and `*(ar+i)` is actually refers to the content of the address location of `ar+i`, but I don't understand how it will work with `*(ar+i)+j`, it's like content + a number.

one more thing is,

```
(1) char *ptr; ptr = "This is a string";
(2) char *ptr = "This is a string";
```

Why (1) can not be `char *ptr; *ptr="this a string"` when declaration and assignment are separated?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Outside of a declaration, unary `*` is the *dereference* operator. Look it up in your text book.

Comment: For question 2, char *ptr = "This is a string"; implicitly puts the string on the heap, however you do not need to free it. char* ptr; declares a undefined pointer, so dereferencing it is bad. So, it's basically just a short, convenience thing. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: To elaborate on what @6502 says, the string is not put on the heap, but in a read-only data segment. That's a big difference.

Comment: @ben To allocate memory from heap, one would use malloc.

Comment: To your 2nd question, In statement char *ptr; You are basically declaring a pointer and to say why cant you use *ptr = "This is string" is due to how pointers work. In C, first address of string literal is stored in a ptr and assignment operator just does that and from here you can traverse whole string using that pointer. Keep in mind that * literally means "value pointed by" and to write *ptr = "this is string"; will mean value pointer by ptr is "this is string" which is not how C works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first case `ar` is most probably **a pointer to a pointer** (declared as `int **ar;`), thus `*(a + i)` is **a pointer** or an array and `*(*(a + i) + j)` is the element.

In C and C++ however there is a rule that says that an array can implicitly "decay" to a pointer to the first element in many cases and thus it's also possible that `ar` has been declared in other ways:

```
int **ar;     // (1) A pointer to a pointer
int *ar[3];   // (2) An array of pointers
int ar[3][3]; // (3) An array of arrays
```

When writing `ar + i` in case `ar` is an array it decays to a pointer to the first element (case 2 and 3) and the result is the address of a pointer (case 2) or the address of an array (3). Using the dereference operator `*` then gets the element that is either a pointer or an array.

When you the add `j` and the element is an array (case 3) this array also decays to a pointer to its first element before computing the addition. Thus to recap, dependin on how `ar` is defined:

```
ar                // (1) a pointer to a pointer,
                  // (2) a pointer to array,
                  // (3) an array of array

ar + i            // (1) and (2) address of a pointer
                  // (3) address of array

*(ar + i)         // (1) and (2) a pointer
                  // (3) an array

*(ar + i) + j     // address of an integer in any case

*(*(ar + i) + j)  // an integer in any case
```

Don't worry if this seems confusing, because it is. Normally when you use `*(x + i)` is because `x` is a pointer however and that's why I guessed that `ar` has been declared as `int **ar;`. Note also that in C and C++ `*(x + i)` is perfectly equivalent to `x[i]` or even to `i[x]`.

In the second case the reason is how the declaration are written in C.

```
char * s = "foo";
```

should be read as

```
(char *s) = ("foo");  // Not legal C, just to show type declaration and
                      // initialization
```

in other words the `*` is part of the type declaration of `s`, not an operation applied to `s`.

Note however that

```
char *s, t;
```

declares `s` as a `char *` and `t` as a `char`.

Type declarations are probably the most powerful but difficult part of C syntax because it's not obvious what is the part being declared. For example

```
int *(*f)(int *(*g)(int x));
```

is a valid declaration for the type of `f` and the names `g` and `x` are instead irrelevant and could be omitted.

```
int *(*f)(int *(*)(int));  // Same as above
```

The type of `f` in this case is a pointer to a function accepting a pointer to a function accepting an int and returning a pointer to an int, and returning a pointer to an int.

My guess is that the vast majority of C programmers would however need to think a bit before being able to decipher that :-D

Comment: I think you misread the second part of the question. OP is not asking about `const`, he's asking why you don't dereference the pointer `ptr` when you assign to it.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate a bit:

- `a[b]` is always a shorthand of `*(a+b)`.

If you combine that with the pointer arithmetics rules (or derive these from there), any of `a` and `b` can be a pointer, the other one an integer, denoting the offset.

With this rule, you can transform an expression like `*(*(ar + i) + j)` to `*(ar[i] + j)` and then to `ar[i][j]`.

Alas, you don't tell us what your `ar` is, but we can tell the following:

- As `ar[i][j]` is a valid expression, `ar[i]` is a pointer or an array which has decayed into a pointer in this expression.
- The same counts for `ar`.
- In order for this to be true, `ar` can be any of

  - `type** ar`
  - `type (*ar)[]`
  - `type ar[][]`
  - `type * ar[]`

  where `type` is the type of each of the components.

  These four alternatives all have a different memory layout, but are accessed the same way.

That's how pointer arithmetics and array decaying works. Best have a look at a good book or tutorial.

The second question should better be a separate question.

It is just because of the assignment and initialization rules of C.

You define a pointer

- either uninitialized: `type * p;`
- or initialized: `type * p = <init value>;`

but

`p = <new value>;`

is how you assign it.

Keep in mind that a string literal is transformed into the address of that string in its readonly memory section.

Answer (score 1):

For Question 1) `*(*(ar+i)+j)=ar[i][j];`
this is because, ar is base address of the complete 2D array.
And `ar[i]` (or `*(ar+i)`) where `i` goes from 0 to no_of_rows-1 will consist of address of each row in array.
and then `ar[i][j]` (or `*(*(ar+i)+j`)  gives you values at specific addresses.

You should also have a look at memory representation of 2D (also 3D) arrays for more clearance.

For Question 2):

when you say `ptr="abc";` address of string `"abc"` gets stored into `ptr`.

Answer (score 1):

I think `ar` is a pointer to pointer.

```
int **ar;
```

`ar` refers to the address of the pointer `ar` points to, i.e a pointer to pointer to `int`.
`*ar` refers to the content of the address `ar` points to, i.e a pointer to `int`.
`*(*ar)` refers to the content of the address the pointer points to ( to which `ar` points) , i.e an `int`.

> why (1) can not be char *ptr; *ptr="this a string" when declaration and assignment is separated ?

Note that `*` is not an indirection operator when used in declaration. It performs indirection only when it is used as a unary operator in a statement.